# Printing variables and strings in Python

Tags: python, string, printing

I am trying to print the following lines :

'My name is John Smith.'

'My name is John Smith, and I live in CHICAGO'

and I live in chicago'

My code below :

```
 name = 'John Smith'
 age = 25
 location = 'CHICAGO' # change this to lower case when printing
 print('My name is %s.')
  print('My name is %s, and I live in %s' )
  print(f'My name is {name}.')
  'and I live in location.lower()
```

How can I get the results from the top?

Comment: What is `text`?

Comment: This looks like copied/pasted lines from several online resources found on the Internet. They are a mixture of different methods (some now obsolete). To be frank this is not the best way to learn a programming language. Try following an up-to-date introductory Python tutorial first.

Comment: Why is the last one missing the `print` call -- is that a copy/paste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

name = 'john smith'
age = 25
location = 'chicago'
print ('My name is %s, and I live in %s. I am %s years old.' %  (name, location, str(age)))
```

Output:

My name is john smith, and I live in chicago. I am 25 years old.

By the way i recommend you to read this article: https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/

Answer (score 0):

You can use f-strings for all of them. Use the `lower()` method to convert the location to lowercase.

```
print(f'My name is {name}')
print(f'My name is {name}, and I live in {location}')
print(f'and I live in {location.lower()}')
```